# How do I hide the filename of each video when playing a playlist with PotPlayer?

Tags: daum-pot-player

I've been asked to write some Python code to control a big screen at a trade show, and I'm using PotPlayer to play the videos because it has gapless playback, but when each video plays it still shows the video's filename in the top-left corner of the screen.  I don't see anything in the Preferences that would let me hide this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open PotPlayer.
2. Right-click anywhere on the screen to open the context menu.
3. Click on “Preferences”.
4. In the left pane, click on “OSD”.
5. In the right pane, uncheck “Filename” under “Information”.
6. Click “OK” to save changes

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVLW6.jpg).

Comment: I don't have time to verify your answer but I'm going to guess it's correct.  If someone else replies and says it doesn't work, I'll change my vote.